# How to replace each element of the list with the sum of the elements of the list up to the position of the element inclusive

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, sum

I have a list that contain days count in each month:

```
month = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
```

I want to transform list above. Each element of the new list is equal to the sum of all elements in a particular position. For example, first element should be the same (31), second = 28+31, third = 31+28+31 and so on.
Desired output:

```
month = [31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365]
```

How to do it? I tried variations with a for loop and append method, but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this isn't tagged `numpy`, I think you would greatly benefit from `np.cumsum` (cumulative sum) rather than looping:

```
import numpy as np

np.cumsum(month)

array([ 31,  59,  90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365])
```

Alternatively, you could use this list comprehension:

```
[sum(month[:i+1]) for i in range(len(month))]

[31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365]
```

As pointed out by @PatrickHaugh, you could also use [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
import itertools

# Cast it to list to see results (not necessary depending upon what you want to do with your results)
list(itertools.accumulate(month))

[31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365]
```

Comment: thanks, that` s exactly what i need (list comprehension)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I would use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) over importing `numpy` (Assuming you're using Python >= 3.2)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickHaugh, I included it in my edited answer (with credit :))